# Mysql - LEFT JOIN - get first entry

Tags: mysql, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have this structure in MySql

[image: tables]

I am trying to get:

**FIRST post, from LAST topic WHERE category is 'News'**

In this example it is row from post where id = 2 as marked on image

[image: row]

So far I got this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM forum_post AS p 
LEFT JOIN forum_topic AS t ON p.topic_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN forum_category AS c ON t.category_id = c.id
WHERE c.title = 'News' AND t.id = MAX(t.id)
ORDER BY p.id ASC LIMIT 1
```

**EDIT:**

Dirty solution:

```
SELECT * FROM forum_post
WHERE topic_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM forum_topic WHERE category_id = 1)
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Last Topic = Max(Topic_Id) ?

Comment: yes, last topic will be always at end of table

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak Check out sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1):

You can still use a joined query instead of a subquery to get the first post from last topic of your category,note the subquery in join will run only once to get the result set and in your case subquery will run for each iteration

```
SELECT * FROM
forum_post AS p 
  JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      t.id 
    FROM
      forum_topic AS t 
      JOIN forum_category AS c 
        ON t.category_id = c.id 
    WHERE c.title = 'News' 
    ORDER BY t.id DESC 
    LIMIT 1) t
  ON p.topic_id = t.id 
ORDER BY p.id ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select fp.* from forum_post fp,
(select min(fp.id) from forum_post fp where topic_id in 
 (select max(ft.id) from forum_topic ft inner join forum_category fc 
     on fc.id = ft.category_id where fc.title = 'News'))T 
where fp.id = T.id
```

[In case there are no forum_posts, no row will be returned]

Edit:
Updated [Although I haven't tried executing it]

Comment: #1052 - Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

I haven't test it, but it shoud be something like this:

```
SELECT fm.remply
FROM forum_topic ft
JOIN forum_category fc
    ON ft.category_id = fc.category_id
    AND fc.title = 'News'
JOIN forum_post fm
    ON ft.id = fm.topic_id
ORDER BY ft.id DESC
        ,fm.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```